# Accessing old games in my playstation plus subscription

Tags: ps-vita, playstation-plus

I have a 1 year playstation plus subscription playing on my ps4, six month passed now from this subscription. I want to buy a new playstation vita.

My question is, will I be able to download the old games from the six months that have already passed in my subscription? Or I will be only able to download the games starting from the day I bought this PSVita?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You will only be able to download the games from past PS Plus months if you specifically claimed the games during the month they were available. You can claim games you don't actually have the console for, but you do have to claim them all individually to add them to your download list.

If you added the Vita games by completing the checkout in the Playstation store every month, then they are already in your download list and you can use them on your new Vita.

Any games you didn't claim in the month they were available can not be added anymore.

As games from other platforms may not show up on your console store (e.g. PS3 plus games don't show up in the PS4 store), you can use the PC store to claim games on all platforms, including ones you don't yet own, at [store.playstation.com](https://store.playstation.com). Here, you can also view your download list and see which Vita titles you already have. You can download all Vita games that show up in that list once you have the platform.

Comment: Thanks so much i got it today i found that i can download the psvita game even if i don't have the console yet.

Answer (score -1):

Your games are linked to your account so aslong you have your account and a active subscription you should be able to download all games available for your account.

> Q: I’m already a PS3 Plus member. Do I need to buy a separate
>   membership to get Plus on PS Vita?
>
> A: We’re happy to say that it’s one Plus membership to access all Plus
>   benefits across these two devices. It’s not simply an introductory
>   offer, it’s the way it is as far as Plus access on both PS Vita and
>   PS3.

[Source](http://community.us.playstation.com/t5/Forum-Frequently-Asked-Questions/PlayStation-Plus-FAQ/td-p/37512373)